# Work done by moving a body moving on a circular path

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, rotational-dynamics, work

> A body moving in circular path of radius $8\sqrt{2}m$ is acted upon by force:
>    $-y\hat i +x\hat j$. Find work done by its complete revolution.

So I was trying this question and I could solve it in using one method but not with another method that I tried.
My method 1:
So the easy method to solve it is to see that this force is tangential to the path in nature. So work done by it =Magnitude of force×distance travelled.
ie. $2 × \pi × 8 \sqrt{2} × \sqrt{2} = 32\pi$ which is the correct answer.
However the problem arises in the second method:
Let the work done by the force equal  integration $f\cdot dx +f\cdot dy$
This equals integration $-ydx +xdy$.             ...(1)
Replacing $y$ with root of $((8\sqrt{2})^2- y^2 )$ (since circular path.)
Similarly replacing $x$ in  ......(1)
Now Integrating the the function with limits $0$ to $0$. 
This results in the answer coming out as $0$.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have to parametrize the path, or break it up into parts. Also your change of variables doesn't make sense. Do you mean to replace x (not y) with $\sqrt{r^2-y^2}$? You only need to replace one variable if you want to integrate over the other (and then break the integral into two parts to avoid an integral with the same start and end limits).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your first answer is incorrect. The magnitude of the force$^*$ is not $\sqrt 2$, so I am unsure how the answer you have was confirmed to be correct. But since you are asking about the second, more involved way, I will let you find your mistake and jump into the answer to the question.

---

A small amount of work done at some point around the circle is given by $dW=\vec F \cdot d\vec s$ where $d\vec s$ is a small displacement. Therefore,

$$dW=(-y \hat i+x\hat j)\cdot(dx\hat i + dy\hat j)=-y\cdot dx+x\cdot dy$$

which is what you have in your question.

Now, it seems like you want to keep things in terms of $x$ or $y$, and not move to polar coordinates, so I will continue to do this. We can express one spatial coordinate in terms of the other using the fact that the path the object takes is a circle. Therefore, let's express $y$ in terms of $x$.
$$y=\sqrt{R^2-x^2}$$
where $R$ is the radius of the circle. This also means that
$$dy=-\frac{x}{\sqrt{R^2-x^2}}dx$$

Therefore,

$$dW=-\left(\sqrt{R^2-x^2}+\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{R^2-x^2}}\right)dx$$

Now we can integrate this with respect to $x$. The problem, as you state in the question, is that if you try to integrate along the entire path now, you will get $0$ since your lower and upper limits will be the same. This is because our change of variables for $y$ is not valid at all points along the path. It is only valid for positive $y$. Therefore, one way to do the work integral would be to break it up into two parts, one for when $y$ is positive and one for when $y=-\sqrt{R^2-x^2}$ is negative. However, we can exploit symmetry in the system by recognizing that the work done over the first half of the path is equal to work done on the second half (technically you can pick any fraction of the path, as long as along that part the change of variables is correct as explained above)

Therefore the total work is
$$W=-2\int_{R}^{-R} \left(\sqrt{R^2-x^2}+\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{R^2-x^2}}\right)dx$$

I will leave performing the integral to you.

---

The integral is much easier to do in polar coordinates. The easiest way to set up the integral is to realize two things. First, the force can be expressed as $\vec F=R\hat\theta$. Second, the displacement vector around the circle is just $d\vec s=Rd\theta\hat\theta$. Therefore, at any point along the circle 
$$\vec F \cdot d\vec s=R^2d\theta$$

So the work done by the force around the circle is
$$W=\int_0^{2\pi}R^2d\theta$$

This is a much easier integral than the one above, but it is pretty much the same thing as your first method (with the appropriate corrections).

---

*Technically the expression for your force should have some sort of constant factor multiplying it with units $N/m$. But since you didn't give it this way, I did not include it as well.